# javascript storage class for reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi is it possible to add class to element and storage it in element if the page reloads  ?

```
<button></button>
<div class=""></div>

$(document).ready(function () {

   $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").addClass("test");
 });

});
```

Comment: Yes, localStorage, now to find a dupe since it is asked pretty often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function() {
   $("div").addClass("test");
   localStorage['testClass'] = 'test';
  });  
  previousTestClass = localStorage['testClass'];
  if (previousTestClass) 
  $('div').addClass(previousTestClass); 
});
```